# Element list dynamically loading a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

i'm having a list,what i want to do is when a user click on the list item sport1 it will show him results from database(table sport1)
when he click on list item education1,reqults from table education1 will be shown.
the problem is not how to retrieve data from database,the problem is to stay in the same page and when a user click on an item it required data would be retrieved,i tried using data filters but it doesn't work.
I appreciate your help guys.

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a name="sport1" href="#"  class="active">
      <h5>Sport</h5>
      </a></li>
    <li><a name="education1" class="" href="#" >
      <h5>Education</h5>
      </a></li>
    <li><a name="Loisir1" href="#" >
      <h5>Loisir et detente </h5>
      </a></li>
    <li><a name="Culturel1" href="#" >
      <h5>Culturel</h5>
      </a></li>
    <li><a name="Equipement1" href="#" >
      <h5>Equipement public</h5>
      </a></li>
    <li><a name="Regeneration1" href="#" >
      <h5>Regeneration urbaine</h5>
      </a></li>
     <li><a name="Residentiel1" href="#">
      <h5>Residentiel</h5>
      </a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Look into AJAX requests (XMLhttp requests) in Javascript. This allows you send a request to a URL, particularly a PHP file that fetches this data from the database, and then interpret the response in Javascript without ever leaving the page.

Comment: You can use AJAX. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) is a good tutorial.

Comment: a want to use the same role as data-filters but in other way !

Comment: You mean HTML5 data-* filters? They will not fetch the data for you. Javascript/AJAX will do that.

Comment: how to that then ! simple way !

Answer (score 1):

Create something like this using jquery (requires jquery):

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
        <a id="sport1" name="sport1" href="#"  class="active" onclick="showResults(this)"> <h5>Sport</h5></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>
function showResults(obj) {
    var item = $(obj).attr('id');
    $.get('/somewebservice/'+item, function(result) {
        //display results
        for(var i in result) {
            // render result
        }
    },'json');
});
</script>
```

Comment: First, you must have jquery setup on your page.  Second, you must replace somewebservice with a valid call that is going to return the result set in json format.  If you just want to return in text format, then changed 'json' to 'text'.  See http://customwebservicespro.com/test.html for an example.

Comment: One item, I have a typo at the bottom of the funciton.  Remove ");" from "});"